# Do the x86 virtualization instruction sets (VT-x, AMD-V) have alternate uses?

Tags: virtualization, x86

Hardware-assisted virtualization provides a great pathway to efficiently and securely running guest operating systems atop a hypervisor.

Do those instruction sets (such as Intel's VT-x, AMD's AMD-V, and the Extended Page Tables extension) provide value for scenarios *other* than running a guest OS wholesale? For example, could they be used to sandbox processes or prevent pieces of kernel-mode code from doing things they shouldn't?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Going through the Intel's own page on ["Hardware assisted virtualization"](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/virtualization/virtualization-technology/hardware-assist-virtualization-technology.html) , they mention a couple of interesting applications:

> **1. Industrial systems**: Virtualization enables systems to
>   simultaneously run real-time and general-purpose operating systems,
>   each on dedicated processor cores of an Intel® multi-core processor.

This is different from running a guest-OS. Here the VT-x features can be used to run two different Operating Systems in parallel, so that we can combine the best of both to achieve our goals. For example, a scenario where you needed very high precision real-time data monitoring, *and* very high speed processing: In this case, the data acquisition could be entirely delegated to an RTOS running on one of the cores, whereas the other ran a GPOS to process the data.

> **2. Medical devices**: Securing applications and patient data is
>   essential for medical diagnostic equipment. Applications requiring a
>   higher level of security can be isolated using Intel VT, which
>   protects their memory space in hardware and helps prevent attacks from
>   malicious software. As such, software running in a secure partition
>   only has access to its own code and data regions, unable to page
>   outside its memory boundary because the hardware precludes
>   unauthorized access.

As they mention, the memory space protection implemented in VT allows software to run only its own code, and access only its own memory spaces. This has a lot of potential in e-security.

Comment: These applications are particular cases of running multiple OSes on the same processor.

Comment: No, these are examples of running applications on different cores on the same processor... Especially in first scenario.

Comment: Yes, they are particular cases of running multiple OSes on the same processor (an RTOS and a GPOS in example 1, an OS for high-security applications and an OS for low-security applications in example 2). Each OS does of course run its own applications.

Comment: Can the down-voter please let me know the issue with my answer?

Comment: On what do you base your last use case? What is "slightly more privileged"? Why would games running in a more privileged level have better performance?

Comment: @Nikopol -  that was speculative, and took it off.

Answer (score 5):

> Do those instruction sets (such as Intel's VT-x, AMD's AMD-V, and the Extended Page Tables extension) provide value for scenarios other than running a guest OS wholesale?

An additional use case for virtualization extensions is to run a [**bare metal hypervisor**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor#Classification) (also called *type 1 hypervisor*). Apart from being able to run multiple OSs on top, you can also run bare metal applications directly on top of the hypervisor (not inside a guest OS instance) *alongside* regular virtualized OSs. The hypervisor can guarantee security such that these applications can run critical systems like medical equipment. If a guest OS crashes, the hypervisor would ensure that bare metal applications are not affected.

> For example, could they be used to sandbox processes?

They can be used to sandbox processes, but that's what regular operating systems do as well.

> or prevent pieces of kernel-mode code from doing things they shouldn't?

This is actually what is happening when virtualized guest operating systems are trying to execute [**sensitive instructions**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popek_and_Goldberg_virtualization_requirements), which are instructions that can *alter* the execution of the machine that can be run in the *unprivileged mode* of the architecture.